# Node Event Loop Confusion

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, nonblocking

I am a bit confused and don't know if I fully understand the nodeJS event loop/non-blocking I/O concepts.

Let's say in my server I have:

```
app.get('/someURL', AuthHandler.restrict, MainHandler.findAllStocksFromUser);
```

And findAllStocksFromUser() is defined like so:

```
findAllStocksFromUser(req,res) {
     /* Do some terribly inefficient, heavy computation*/
     res.send(/*return something*/);
}
```

So now let's say 5 requests come in. As I understand, with each request that comes in, a callback, in this case findAllStocksFromUser(), is added to the eventloop queue, and with every tick, the callbacks are called.

Questions:

1. The "terribly inefficient, heavy computation" won't effect the server's ability to efficiently receive requests as they come in and immediately add their callbacks to the queue, correct?
2. But the "terribly inefficient, heavy computation" is going to block the other callbacks until it's done and cause the server to be inefficient in that way, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In node.js, your Javascript is single threaded.  That means that only one piece of Javascript is run at a time.  So, once a request handler starts running, it keeps running until it either finishes entirely and returns back to the system that called it or until it starts an async operation (DB, file, network, etc...) and then returns back to the system that called it.  Only then, can other requests start processing.

So, if your "heavy computation" is truly lots of synchronous Javascript running, then no other requests will process while that is running.  If that "heavy computation" actually has lots of async operations in it, then other requests will get to run while the handlers waits for responses from the async operations.

Now, to your specific questions:

> So now let's say 5 requests come in. As I understand, with each
>   request that comes in, a callback, in this case
>   findAllStocksFromUser(), is added to the eventloop queue, and with
>   every tick, the callbacks are called.

This isn't quite correct.  The incoming request is queued, but it is queued at a level much lower than just queuing your callback.  It's queued before the Javascript part of your server even sees the request (in native code somewhere).

> The "terribly inefficient, heavy computation" won't effect the
>   server's ability to efficiently receive requests as they come in and
>   immediately add their callbacks to the queue, correct?

The incoming requests will be queued by the underlying TCP infrastructure or by the native code in node.js which implements your server (which is not running in single-threaded JS).  So, a long running piece of Javascript won't keep incoming requests from getting queued (unless some internal queue fills up).

> But the "terribly inefficient, heavy computation" is going to block
>   the other callbacks until it's done and cause the server to be
>   inefficient in that way, right?

Correct.  If this inefficient, heavy computation is synchronous code, then it runs until it is done and no other requests get to run while it is running.

The usual solution to heavy computation code in node.js is to either redesign it to run faster or to use async operations where possible or to move it out of the main process and fire up a child process or a cluster of child workers to handle the heavy computation.  This then allows your main request handler to treat this heavy computation as an asynchronous operation and allow other things to run while that heavy-duty work is being done outside the main node.js thread.

Though this is sometimes more coding work, it is also possible to break a long running computation into chunks so that a chunk of work can be executed and then use `setImmediate()` to schedule the next chunk of work, allowing other queued items to be processed between your chunks of work.  Since it's fairly quick these days to just set up a pool of workers that you pass off the work to, I'd probably favor that approach as it also gives you a better shot at utilizing multiple CPUs and it saves the complication of "chunking" the work and writing code to efficiently process that way.

Comment: Thank you. By "no other requests get to run while it is running" do you mean other requests can't be received by the server and their respective callbacks can't be put in the queue, or, the callbacks already on the queue can't run? Or both?

Comment: @user2680392 - the server's native code and OS will queue incoming requests pretty much no matter what (until some high limits are reached) so you don't have to worry about requests getting dropped when the server is momentarily busy.  But, things already in the queue will not run until whatever JS request in node.js that is currently running finishes or starts waiting for some async operation.

Comment: A great answer containing a bunch of insight into how node works from the coders perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will affect it. Node.js is single-threaded. It means that the "terribly inefficient, heavy calculation" will block **everything** while being processed.

This is easy to test : send several requests and see their response times. Or just send a really big JSON file (it will have to be parsed, which can be slow), and again measure the response times.

You could break the computations into smaller chunks to improve the efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would cause inefficiencies on the server. The first request to the server would block all other requests from being processed since the javascript event loop runs on a single thread.

All other requests would have to wait because the event loop is blocked by the first **findAllStocksFromUser** task to reach the server.